# Hide div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide some div. Just look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/eBcRP/). Here i want to hide after the count is "1".

```
$(".prev").click(function(){
   var current = $('ul li.selected').index(),
    maxIndex = $('ul li').length - 1,
    prev = (current - 1) >  maxIndex ? 0 : (current - 1);

   manageControls(prev);
   setActive(prev);

  });
```

Can any one help ?

Comment: i want to hide div if prev reach count  1.

Comment: div name is myclass. i want to hide all of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eBcRP/1/) ???

```
if (prev != -1) {
    manageControls(prev);
    setActive(prev);
}else{
    $('.myclass').add('ul li.selected').removeClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: @SperanskyDanil - a little bit of both ?